# Help getting HDD mounted as Root

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Thanks to all the tech gurus who are willing to help noobs like me!

I'm trying to mount my hard drives in a way that Plex Media Server will be able to access them. When trying to mount my secondary internal HDD, I get this error:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: only root can mount /dev/sdb1 on /mnt/media_sdb1
```

Comment: try typing `sudo ` before the command you use. example: `sudo mount ...`

Comment: Thanks... I was trying to mount it from the Disk Utility... I'll go through the terminal as you suggested...

Answer (score 1):

There are some help pages on using mount [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mount-umount-examples/) and [here](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm) - basically, use this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/media_sdb1
```

which use the syntax:

```
sudo mount /dev/DEVICE /PATH/TO/DESTINATION
```

These all need to typed in terminal, which in Unity can be accessed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks to you all!! Loving Linux, HATE BILL GATES' GLOBALIST EUGENICS LOVING BUTT!

Comment: Glad it worked - mark it as answered then :-)

Comment: yep, upvote it and accept it